# laravel fortify Remember me Functionality in login

Tags: laravel, fortify, remember-me

please pardon my English since it's not my mother language so the problem is that I'm using fortify Auth and using also custom roles (admin and user) and I want to use remember me functionality to save also the user role with remember me a cookie ,can anyone help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working code from one of my projects:

```
<div class="block mt-4">
                    <label for="remember_me" class="flex items-center  text-right">
                        <input id="remember_me" type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox border" name="remember">
                        <span class="ml-2 text-sm text-gray-600">{{ __('Remember me?') }}</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
```

Feel free to adjust the styling to your needs

Answer (score 0):

You need to add field with name 'remember' like checkbox in your login form